# TypeError: Greeter.deployed(...).setGreeting is not a function

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment

I start `truffle console` and type `Greeter.deployed().setGreeting("Hello world!");`

I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Greeter.deployed(...).setGreeting is not a function
```

How can I solve this issue? Hoping your answer！Like the following diagram：
[image]

Comment: Please share the contract code as you deployed it.

Comment: This is function code（a part in Greeter.sol）“ function setGreeting(string _newgreeting) 
    {
        greeting = _newgreeting;
    }
    ”

Comment: `.deployed()` returns a promise. Try `Greeter.deployed().then(i=>i.setGreeting("hello"))`

Comment: I‘m sorry to bother you again，but the result of my tutorial is this：          
 $ truffle console
truffle(default)> Greeter.deployed().setGreeting("Hello world!");
'0xf6a00b4466c9ab38d7eb60dc9f8d15f5f1e500e24ea91bd9e28f6233bad08aed'
truffle(default)> Greeter.deployed().greet.call();
'Hello world!'
truffle(default)>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
Greeter.deployed().setGreeting("Hello world!");
```

Does not work because `.deployed()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). There's no `setGreeting` function on a Promise.

Instead you should do

```
Greeter.deployed().then(instance => {
  instance.setGreeting("hello world");
});
```

You can type it in one line `Greeter.deployed().then(i=>i.setGreeting("hello world"))`

Comment: You are knowledgeable！！！cool

Comment: I try it successfully，but I have one more，when I run“User.deployed().then(i=>i.User("3","2","1"))” in another contract and error is：  TypeError: i.User is not a function
    at User.deployed.then.i (evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:27)    How to deal with it？Do you like to have a look my code of “User.sol”?